# Word, Idiom or phrase for "trying" or "considering to do something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Please look at following statements.

> 1. Solution to the problem was so big or complicated that, I didn't even
>    ____(tried or considered trying) it.
> 2. That area is so dangerous that, I wouldn't even _____ to go there.

So, are there any **idioms/ words/ phrases** that fit in the sentences above? as opposed to simple "try" word?

Comment: I think the modest "dare" is there for such purposes; give these poor "folks" a chance sometimes.Why has it to be an idiom or a fancy word all the time? Plus it saves space as Strunk often advised. Thus: 1) Solution to the problem was so complicated that I didn't even dare to try/attempt it. 2) The area is so dangerous that I wouldn't even dare to go there.

Comment: If "dare" sounds too pedestrian, try this idiom (of course, you'll have to rephrase your sentences) ---Get butterflies in your stomach.

Comment: That area is so dangerous that I wouldn't even think of / contemplate / consider going there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Attempt**" seems to be the verb you're looking for.

OED

> **I. To try, endeavour, essay.**
>
> **1. transitive. To make an effort, to use one's endeavour to do or accomplish some action:**
>
> **a. with infinitive. To endeavour, try**
>
> 1818   S. T. Coleridge Friend (new ed.) I. 256   *The truths, we may attempt to communicate.*
>
> 1876   J. R. Green Short Hist. Eng. People (1882) i. §3. 22   *To attempt the conversion of the English.*